# $G$ be a group where $G= \mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_8$ and the normal subgroup $H=\langle(2,4)\rangle$ use orders of elements to determine...

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

I have the elements of $H$:
$\langle(2,4)\rangle={(2,4),(4,0),(0,4),(2,0),(4,4),(0,0)}$
where $|G/H|=8$

possible isomorphic classes:
$\mathbb{Z}_8$ ,$\mathbb{Z}_4\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$, $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$

I know

$\mathbb{Z}_6 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_8$ has an element of order $8$ and $\mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$  has no element of order $8$, so that leaves $G/H$ is either isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_8$ or $\mathbb{Z}_4 \oplus \mathbb{Z}_2$.

I don't know how to find which one it is between those two.
I know I need to compare the orders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find an isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1018593/find-an-isomorphism)

Answer (score 1):

But $\mathbb Z_4\oplus\mathbb Z_2$ similarly has no element of order $8$.

The question, though,  is does $G/H$ have an element of order $8$; or an element of order $4$.  It doesn't have an element of order $8$,  because the coset $(0,1)+H$ has order $4$. And we can see that no other coset has order $8$.

So there's our answer:  $\mathbb Z_4\oplus\mathbb Z_2$.